# Ecmascript get all the StartDate field values from Sharepoint List into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, jquery-ui, sharepoint, list

I have a Jquery UI datepicker calendar, that should have clickable dates on only those dates that are in the 'startdate' field of a sharepoint list. To make that possible, i need to access the list using Ecmascript, get all the values from 'StartDate' field into  a javascript Array. If I have a List called SchoolSports with fields like Title, startdate and EndDate:

Title------ --StartDate ------        EndDate---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Volleyball---       1/1/2012 ---         1/1/2012--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hockey------            1/2/2012----           1/2/2012

I need an array ActiveDates[]=[1,2] so i can plug these values in the calendar to make only those clickable so users know what programs are there in those dates? Is this achievable? Can someone guide me?

Comment: Who are these wise people that are giving me -ve remark? If you can't help me or don't want to help me, then I don't have a problem. Isn't this a place where you can share your ideas? You ask me something you are not sure of..that i might know about, I will be glad to give my two cents without whining whether you did any research or not!!

Comment: Can you post some code which demonstrates what you have tried so far?  Your question is quite broad and this community prefers to give people guidance on actual code samples rather than general questions about direction.

Answer (score 0):

To load list items from "SchoolSports" list, you can use Darren Johntstones "SPAPI" library (a wrapper around Sharepoint ASMX web services). The original site is dead, but you can download it from a (slightly less documented) mirror: http://zer0c00l.in/wiki/index.php?title=SharePoint_SPAPI_HowTO

When you have loaded the events, it's just a question of updating your datepicker with the values from ajax results.